# CSV reading failing for csv ( ","), getting result as single line

Tags: c#, csv, filestream

I am using C# to develop a Small app which converts csv file to a readable format.

Below is the of sample in CSV file

```
"Symbol","Date","Expiry","Strike Price","Open","High","Low","Close","LTP"   
"5000","6000","4500","45855" ............
```

over 300 lines like this.

```
public List<string[]> parseCSV(string path)
{
  List<string[]> parsedData = new List<string[]>();

  try
  {
    using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(path))
    {
      string line;
      string[] row;

      while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
        row = line.Split(',');  // <<< this ',' is not working 
        parsedData.Add(row);
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
  }

  return parsedData;
}
```

According to the data, I should get new line at LTP, but it's not happening and more than than I am getting result as single line . If add the list ie parseData it is showing as single row.

Comment: [Stop Rolling Your Own CSV Parser!](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp)

Comment: You should not reinvent the wheel, use one of the existing csv-parser like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Comment: As others have stated you should really use a 3rd party framework like FileHelpers

Comment: But what is the solution for above issue ?? is it not solvable ??

Comment: @Vishwa: Your question is not really clear, what doesn't work, what is [LTP](http://www.abbreviations.com/term/246641)?

Comment: @chiccodoro nah :) Its just a suggestion, not answer for current problem.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter,LTP is the last item in the line. after that csv reader should go to the next line  but it is not happening . all ements in this csv file showing as single line .

Comment: This works as should be. What do you mean by that : `all ements in this csv file showing as single line` ?

Comment: @Reniuz: IMO it is an answer. Although not the answer that the OP expected, it solves the problem, even anticipates any future problems, and seems to be supported by the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have stated rolling your own CSV parser is difficult and error prone. My personal preference lies with the [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) library and to show you how good and easy it is I have included a working example with **your** data:

```
using System;
using FileHelpers;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            /*
            Sample data from TestData.csv
                "Symbol","Date","Expiry","StrikePrice","Open","High","Low","Close"
                "MSF","20090913","03032012","1.233","1.1","14.54","0.07","14.11"
                "APL","20111225","31122011","30.09","31.1","33.33","29.11","33.13"
            */

            var engine = new FileHelperEngine<StockModel>();
            engine.Options.IgnoreFirstLines = 1; // skip the header line

            StockModel[] stocks = engine.ReadFile(@"TestData.csv");

            Console.Read();

        }
    }

    [DelimitedRecord(",")]
    public class StockModel
    {
        [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
        public string Symbol;

        [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
        [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "ddMMyyyy")]
        public DateTime Date;

        [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
        [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "ddMMyyyy")]
        public DateTime Expiry;

        [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
        [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal, ".")]
        public decimal StrikePrice;

        [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
        [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal, ".")]
        public decimal Open;

        [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
        [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal, ".")]
        public decimal High;

        [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
        [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal, ".")]
        public decimal Low;

        [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
        [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal, ".")]
        public decimal Close;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , the example you have shown is very help full ,in fact i am using the Indian stock market NSE data . i will use  file helper.

Comment: i am getting some erro  here its telling "Positive number required.Parameter name: length 1" what is this ??

Answer (score -2):

Your code works as expected. Just copied/pasted it and it returns a list that contains 2 elements, one for each line. Each element is a string array, the first have 9 elements the second have 4.

Concerning the "stop reinventing the wheel", I personally disagree. Parsing a CSV file is a simple process, you just have to read line by line and call `.Split(delimiter)`. If a such simple process requires a specific library, every project would have 500+ dependencies.

If you do not have special requirements such as multiple delimiters, async parsing or anything that is not already supported by your own code, I wouldn't use a lib.

Remember using a lib also introduces a lot of potential problems in your project (license issues, testability, extensibility of the code which is often not trivial as you do not own the code, portability, bugs...).

Comment: you are right. this is forum is to help and give solutions .any how i got answer thank you very much instead of "," i used " " , it worked for me

Comment: I really HATE fire-and-forget downvotes. At least explain by leaving a comment...